# i can't connection to remote host sqlserver on Linux mint18 was asp.net core ef core

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

System: Linux mint 18
.netcore:2.0

SQL Server:2008 r2 \ ubuntu SQL Server2017

I was using asp.net core, when the SQL Server connectionString was

```
localhost. <Server=localhost;Database=ryxz;uid=sa;pwd=Zabc123456;>
```

I can connect to this server.

When the connectionString was

```
<Server=59.110.110.110;Database=ryxz;uid=ryxz;pwd=ryxz123456;>
```

like this, I always get an error:

> Connection time out

System:win10

using connection string was

```
<Server=59.110.110.110;Database=ryxz;uid=ryxz;pwd=ryxz123456;>
```

same project same code. Can connect to server.

So can anybody teach me how to do that?

Comment: Do you still connect locally?

Comment: The difference between 1st and 2nd connection string is in protocols used. You use Shared memory in 1st case and TCP\IP in the second, even if locally. So at least you need your TCP\IP to be enabled on the server